# django, where the 'auth.User' comes from?

Tags: django, django-models

In some project, I found that the app's model definition are like this:

```
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
```

my question is where the 'auth.User' comes from?

Is it imported from django.contrib.auth.  But, User not in `auth/__init__.py` file.

How does django know, to find User in `auth/models.py` file ?

Comment: it's from the settings.py, you need to define your own extended user

Comment: can you show the app's source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django always assumes a models module inside an app. So what this means is that django will look for auth.models and inside it will search for a class named `User`. The lookup starts in the `add_lazy_relation` function in `django/db/models/fields/related.py`. As you can see in the source, when passed a string it gives you three options, you can pass `'self'` which will be a relationship to the current model or you can pass `'MyModel'` which will look for the `'MyModel'` class inside the models module in the current app. And last you can pass `'AnotherApp.AnotherModel'` which will look for `'AnotherApp.models.AnotherModel'`. If curious, the model lookup functionality is implemented in `django.db.models.get_model`